# Animating bones causes odd deformation

Tags: animation, bones, keyframes

I pose my hand like this.
[image: posed hand]

I go through and LocRot and the second I move off the keyframe it deforms into this.
[image: animated hand]

Comment: Please use a descriptive title and question body in your posts, also post images locally using the built-in toolbar icon

Comment: Posting the blend file would greatly help. Things like this are almost always impossible to troubleshoot from images.

Comment: Could you provide a .blend file to be able to have a look and try to help you?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you forgot to keyframe those two individual bones. Make sure they are selected, then add the keyframe when they are in the position you want them in.

If they are *already keyframed* earlier in the timeline, in a different position, when you move your timeline cursor they will ***jump back*** to the position they were in at the earlier keyframe.

Make sure you are **on the frame in which you would like to place the key**, then do the bone movement, **then place a key before changing frames**.

Perhaps you would rather remove the original keyframe instead. This will avoid the jumping, and the bones will stay in the position you left them.

Another possibility is that you accidentally added a keyframe later in the animation, causing this problem. Maybe there is one on the frame next to the one you are on?

I'm sorry if this doesn't answer your question, but I do not have any other reasons why this problem is occurring from your post.

Comment: Not its after I LocRot or even before all I do is make one frame so nothing is changing there.. It's just jumping to that as soon as I go to move the keyframe to another.

Comment: Are you pressing "i" on your keyboard while the mouse is over the viewport? If not, that could be your problem. "i" adds a keyframe. Simply pressing LocRot from the menu changes what type of keyframe will be added when "i" is pressed.